# How do I add a parameter (class) to an URL

Tags: html, css, class, url, parameters

**This was the assignment I've got from school:**

*Create a new class selector in the CSS-file named 'current' for the a element in the nav. 
The background color should be `#DB2B2B` and the text color must be white.*

*Next you add the parameter class="current" to the correct link in index.html.*

---

This is code of both the CSS-file and the HTML-file:

**CSS**

```
.current a {
        background-color: #DB2B2B;
        color: white;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
</nav>
```

---

The problem I'm dealing with is that I don't know exactly where I add the parameter and how.
As you might have noticed, the goal is to show on which tab you currently are by giving it a different color and text.

Comment: `<nav class="current">` to target `a`

Comment: `.current a {...}` is wrong. You want `a.current {...}`, then `<a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the code as bellow

```
<nav>
    <a class="current" href="index.html" >Home</a>
</nav>
```

and the css be like below

```
a.current {
    background-color: #DB2B2B;
    color: white;
    }
```

Comment: thanks if the problem is solved you can accept the answer by clickin the tick

Answer (score 0):

add class="current" in `<nav>` html tag

```
 <nav>
        <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
</nav>
```